# Ubuntu 18.04 won't detect external HDMI monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

The external monitor is connected via HDMI, but it's not detected.

Xrandr output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1368 x 768
default connected primary 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768       0.00* 
   1368x768       0.00
```

lspci|grep VGA output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
```